# How to handle callbackquery in python telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In my code I'm facing an issue with callbackquery handler, when I hit /start command the "**Next**" button appears and when I hit on that button it gives me reply as "**hi**", till here the output is correct. Then when I hit another command "/**help**" then "**help**" button appears, when I hit that help button then it gives me previous reply which was "hi", where the output should have been "**help**"

```
 from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
 from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler

 TELEGRAM_HTTP_API_TOKEN = 'token'

 FIRST, SECOND, HELP = range(3)

 def start(bot, update):
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(u"Next", callback_data=str(FIRST))]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text(
            u"Start handler, Press next",
            reply_markup=reply_markup
        )
        return FIRST

 def first(bot, update):
        query = update.callback_query
        #reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                         text='hi')

 def help(bot,update):
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(u"HELP", callback_data=str(HELP))]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text(
            u"Help handler, Press button",
            reply_markup=reply_markup
        )

        return HELP

 def myhelp(bot,update):
        query = update.callback_query
        bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                         text='help')

 updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_HTTP_API_TOKEN)

 conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            FIRST: [CallbackQueryHandler(first)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)]
    )
 conv_handler1=ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('help',help)],
        states={
            HELP: [CallbackQueryHandler(myhelp)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('help',help)]
    )

 updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
 updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler1)

 updater.start_polling()

 updater.idle()
```

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first conversationhandler is still in state `FIRST` en thus is still waiting for callbackqueries. 
Since it's the first handler added and they're in the same group, the first will respond, and the second won't.
You can look at the `pattern` argument for `CallbackQueryHandler` to solve your problem.

Comment: which type of **pattern** argument will solve my problem for **callbackqueryhandler** any reference link for will help solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ending conversation with the usage of `return ConversationHandler.END` will also work as it will end the first conversation.
Refer the example here : https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py